# How to run executable file a.out created in my laptop gcc environment in other laptops?

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

I have written a program code in c compiled and executed in gcc compiler. I want to share the executable file of program without sharing actual source code. Is there any way to share my program without revealing actual source code so that executable file could run on other computers with gcc compilers??

Comment: Just share the compiled file? I don't understand the question..

Comment: yes. without sharing actual source code(.c file), i want to share compiled file(a.out) compiled in gcc compiler

Comment: Why can't you just do it? Share the binary executable.

Comment: Do you want to run shared `a.out` on old environments (older than the one on where you compiled) ?

Comment: Binary executable created in my gcc environment contains my linux os and my environment information. will it run on other machines with gcc environment??

Comment: Other machine means? Same architecture? If not then you need cross compiler and you have to link library statically.

Comment: same architecture, same linux environment

Comment: Then it will depand on version of the standard library for your compiler is installed in your OS by default (which you can't rely on, in general). If you install  same Linux version , on two machine then there is a chance your executable run successfully.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to share my program without revealing actual source code so that executable file could run on other computers with gcc compilers?

**TL;DR**: yes, provided a greater degree of similarity than just having GCC.  One simply copies the binary file and any needed auxiliary files to a compatible system and runs it.

---

### In more detail

It is quite common to distribute compiled binaries without source code, for execution on machines other than the ones on which those binaries were built.  This mode of distribution does present potential compatibility issues (as described below), but so does source distribution.  In broad terms, you simply install (copy) the binaries and any needed supporting files to suitable locations on a compatible system and execute them.  This is the manner of distribution for most commercial software.

#### Architecture dependence

Compiled binaries are certainly specific to a particular hardware architecture, or in certain special cases to a small, predetermined set of two or more architectures (e.g. old Mac universal binaries).  You will not be able to run a binary on hardware too different from what it was built for, but "architecture" is quite a different thing from CPU model.

For example, there is a very wide range of CPUs that implement the x86_64 architecture.  Most programs targeting that architecture will run on any such CPU.  Indeed, the x86 architecture is similar enough to x86_64 that most programs built for x86 will also run on x86_64 (but not *vise versa*).  It is possible to introduce finer-grained hardware dependency, but you do not generally get that by default.

#### Operating system dependence

Furthermore, most binaries are built to run in the context of a host operating system.  You will not be able to run a binary on an operating system too different from the one it was built for.

For example, Linux binaries do not run (directly) on Windows.  Windows binaries do not run (directly) on OS X.  Etc.

#### Library dependence

Additionally, a program built against shared libraries require a compatible version of each required shared library to be available in the runtime environment.  That does not necessarily have to be exactly the same version against which it was built; that depends on the library, which of its functions and data are used, and whether and how those changed over time.

You can sidestep this issue by linking every needed library statically, up to and including the C standard library, or by distributing shared libraries along with your binary.  It's fairly common to just live with this issue, however, and therefore to support only a subset of all possible environments with your binary distribution(s).

#### Other

There is a veritable universe of other potential compatibility issues, but it's unlikely that any of them would catch you by surprise with respect to a program that you wrote yourself and want to distribute.  For example, if you use nVidia CUDA in your program then it might require an nVidia GPU, but such a requirement would surely be well known to you.

Answer (score 1):

Executable are often specific to the environment/machine they were created on. Even if the same processor/hardware is involved, there may be dependencies on libraries that may prevent executables from just running on other machines.

A program that uses only "standard libraries" and that links all libraries statically, does not need any other dependency (in the sense that all the code it need is in the binary itself or into OS libraries that -being part of the system itself- are already on the system).

You have to link the standard library statically. Otherwise it will only work if the version of the standard library for your compiler is installed in your OS by default (which you can't rely on, in general).

Comment: No, that's much too strong.  It is downright *common* to distribute pre-built binaries, including binaries linked against shared libraries.  This does open you up to library compatibility issues, but its not as bad as the execution environment having to have the exact same version of every shared library used.